# QInputdialog not work at static pythonQt callback

Tags: python, qt, static, callback

currently am using pythonQt for embeding python into my qt app. I need to implement a python console within my qt app, for dealing with user python codes: input() or raw_input(), I have to redirect the stdin in python, so I define a static method in my class, show a modal inputdialog, return text user input:

```
static QString myClass::myStdIn(void *callData)
{
   return QFileInputDialog::getText(NULL,....);
}

//then register it to PythonQt in myclass's construct method:
PythonQt::self().setRedirectStdInCallback(myClass::myStdIn,0);
```

the declaration of this method is:

```
void PythonQt::setRedirectStdInCallback (PythonQtInputChangedCB *callback,void *callbackData = 0)
```

myClass::myStdIn seams has to be a static for being registered as a callback.The problem is, when input() or raw_input() is called in python, the app freezed. I tried to use my own modal dialog to replace the QFileInputDialog::getText(), but as long as it is a modal dialog, after execute input() the app will freezed and bug out.

Anyone knows how to deal with this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at the PythonQtScriptingConsole?

```
  connect(PythonQt::self(), SIGNAL(pythonStdOut(const QString&)), this, SLOT(stdOut(const QString&)));
  connect(PythonQt::self(), SIGNAL(pythonStdErr(const QString&)), this, SLOT(stdErr(const QString&)));
```